# Has there been a recent uptick in plzsendtehcodez questions?

Tags: discussion

Lots of 1 rep questions like this lately.

Comment: Yes.  In the fall lots of students have just entered into their first programming class at a university.  However, that may not be the only reason.

Comment: The answer is to vote them down.  If they do the same thing over and over, they will lose the privilege of using SO.

Comment: @CRoss until they, ya know, create another account.

Comment: @drachenstern: they are IP-banned, so it is not quite that simple for them.

Comment: @ether ~ good to know.

Answer (score 2):

Likely those questions were always around, you're just seeing more of them due to the [StackOverflow Homepage Changes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) that went into effect Tuesday.